# loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) { } not calling

Tags: spring, security, saml, onelogin

The steps what i have done:

1. SAML request send to IDP.
2. SAML Response received from IDP to the redirect URL.

But, now i what to read the SAML response object and need to use the details of the user in my application. In this manner, i have implements SAMLUserDetailsService in custom class. Here the loadUserBySAML method is not calling in my application and unable to see the logs in the console. I have enabled the debug as well. Do I need to set any configuration in my application to call this method?

```
@Service
public class MyAppUserDetailsService implements SAMLUserDetailsService{

    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAppUserDetailsService .class);

    @Override
    public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOG.debug("Begin loadUserBySAML MyAppUserDetailsService ");

        LOG.debug("Ended loadUserBySAML NFTFUserDetailsService ");
        return someObject;

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you have already verified that you are getting a SAML token post the login , by using a SAML plugin in your browser....

Comment: Here the IDP i am using is OneLogin. Atfer login into the onelogin site, it was sending the SAML response. But here what my doubt is, when the above method will call in my application.

Comment: Your SAML settings in Onelogin should have the appropriate redirection to your servlet or your application . That is how the Flow will work to call you method.

Answer (score -1):

Once user has been successfully authenticated, the redirection from OneLogin to your application will be done. (This redirection URL might have been configured by your OneLogin admin) Once your application gets hit, this method is going to be called to check the user details through credential object.